# How to write a list with strings and DataFrames into an .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, export-to-csv

i would like to write this list into a .txt file. My Problem is that i cant add the whole data of the 1801*20 matrix.

[image: list]

i tried to convert the list into an pandas DataFrame and write it into an .txt.

```
dftistext = pd.DataFrame(tistext) 
   
dftistext.to_csv('test.txt', mode='a', header=False,index=None)
```

The index 0 string is right but as you can see the DataFrame is not displayed completely. In Addition to that i would like to remove the quotation marks as well.

[image: .txt File output]

thank you for the help!

edit:
now another problem has occurred. When i try to write the pandas DataFrame into the .txt file with `fobj.write(e.to_string(header=False,index=None)+'\n')`, a space is added before each row. I tried to remove it with split():`fobj.write((((e.to_string(header=False,index=None)).lstrip()))+'\n')` but it only works for the first and last row of the 1801 rows. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We make the assumption that you know that you have two types of elements in your list: string and pandas dataframes. So you have to identify across this only two types.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as fobj:
   for e in Liste:
      if isinstance(e, str):
        fobj.write(e + '\n')
      else:
        # The other type -- DataFrame
        fobj.write(e.to_string(header=False,index=None)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear but here are some ways you can print whole `Dataframe`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  
    print(dftistext)
```

You can also extract the Dataframe as `dict` and "pretty print" it:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dftistext.to_dict())
```

From there you can parse and extract anything you need from this into your `.txt` file